# WebStorm complains "not assignable" on returning new object (JSDoc related)

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I have the following JSDoc definition:

```
/**
 * @name DailyCountersNode
 * @type Object
 * @property {number} BuyGold
 * @property {number} BuyStamina
 * @property {number} MarketReset
 * @property {Object.<string,int>} BossCleared
 * @property {Object.<string,int>} BossResets
 * @property {number} NextResetAt
 */
```

and my function return one such structure:

```
/**
 * @return {DailyCountersNode}
 * */
Player.prototype.getDailyCountersNode = function(){
    if(!this.mPlayerData.hasOwnProperty("DailyCounters")){
        var defVal = {
            BuyGold: 0,
            BuyStamina: 0,
            MarketReset: 0,
            BossCleared:{},
            BossResets:{},
            NextResetAt: 0
        };
        return defVal;
    }
    return this.mPlayerData.DailyCounters;
};
```

And I got this warning:

> Returned expression type [BuyGold: number, BuyStamina: number....blah
>   blah blah] is not assignable to type DailyCountersNode

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logged as [WEB-21392](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21392), please follow it for updates. I'd suggest using @typedef instead:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} DailyCountersNode
 * @type Object
 * @property {number} BuyGold
 * @property {number} BuyStamina
...
```

Or, you can use `@return {typeof DailyCountersNode}` instead of `@return {DailyCountersNode}`

Comment: I was actually using @@typedef but webstorm just could not recognize my object correct highlighting all my references everywhere before i switch to use @@name...

Comment: WEB-21392 responded with @return {typeof OBJNAME} which works.
It would be better if you could update the answer for me to mark instead of I submitting another answer to my own question.

Comment: done. But @typedef is also a valid solution, and it works for me

Comment: @len is `typeof` a WebStorm extension of JSDoc?

Comment: typeof is NOT valid in jsdoc, only in typedoc